# Too many redirects .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, vds

I have web-site. At previously host i haven't any problem with `.htaccess` file.
Now i have some problem with `TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.
I need redirect all request from `yzerkalo.ru` or `www.yzerkalo.ru` to `https://**`
I have this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
php_flag display_errors Off

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yzerkalo\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yzerkalo.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.xml [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]

# One month for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

What i'm doing wrong?
That's what i see in Google Chrome [image]

Comment: @Emma no, it's not helped(

Comment: @Emma what's u mean?

Comment: @KoenHollander Emma use this link before

Comment: why this code working on `zerkalo3x.ru` but not working here??

Comment: Maybe some problem with php? or it's unreal?

Comment: @Emma i'm add image loading with slow 3g

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
php_flag display_errors Off

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yzerkalo\.ru [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yzerkalo.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.xml [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]

# One month for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public"
</filesMatch>
```